# How do I pass an array from a branch of the client to python script in the sever?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, react-native

I have a pop up window that creates an array of numbers after selecting a few options on the pop up window. that popup window and array is created under a branch of the client. i then want to press a button that sends that array to a python script, reads it and creates a text file. But how do i pass the array to the python script and how do i run the script from pressing a button on the pop up window? pretty new to this stuff so I am unsure what the best way is to go about this.

Comment: It would be impossible to accurately answer because a lot of details are missing from your question. For example: Why do you need to send an array as opposed to individual elements? How big is the array and what kind of data are you sending? What are you using for network communication(sockets, RPC, etc...)?

Comment: A new case of "Who wants to do my (home) work"